# Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup

I'm trying to publish a reactjs component package following an awesome tutorial by @alexeagleson, however when i try to test the package in another project, It doesn't display and I get the following error...

[image]

I have searched for solutions to no avail. What am I doing wrong and how do I get it fixed?

This is my package.json file and my component

```
  "name": "@okafohenry/react-custom-select",
  "version": "0.0.12",
  "description": "Custom-select: A react component library",
  "scripts": {
    "rollup": "rollup -c"
  },
  "author": "Henry Okafor",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^3.20.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0"
  },
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/okafohenry"
  }
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const CustomSelect = (props: PropsData) => {
  const [ dropdownToggle, setDropdownToggle ] = useState<boolean>(false);


   return(...)
}
```